# Pip not installing in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I gave the command on terminal of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as-

```
 $ sudo apt install python-pip
```

It is giving the error as:

```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install'
> to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
> bcmwl-kernel-source:i386 : Depends: dkms:i386
>                             Depends: linux-libc-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                             Depends: libc6-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                             Depends: linux-headers-generic:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
>                                      linux-headers:i386  dkms : Depends: module-init-tools but it is not going to be installed 
> python-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) but it is
> not going to be installed
>               Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
>               Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
>               Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no
> packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I install pip? Please see to the errors above.

Comment: first run `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: you should see the errors above, it is telling you what to do :) `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install'`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3):

Okay so to get pip you need to install those missing dependencies. Try the following:

`sudo apt-get update`

Then

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Next try:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

If that doesn't work then try with `-f`

For more help check this out :https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: dkms : Depends: module-init-tools but it is not going to be installed               Does this mean I need to install dkms?

Comment: pip installed.Thanks :D

Comment: @ReshuSingh great! Check this as the correct answer! Glad could help!

Answer (score 3):

After searching a lot finally this works for me

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then install pip3 with this command:

```
sudo aptitude install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 1):

run

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Then retry the command, if it still doesn't work, I think you need to `install/upgrade` some packages in errors